# CMake combining 32 bit and 64 bit solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, 32bit-64bit

I am using CMake 2.8.8 to build my project. Is there any way by which I can combine 32 bit and 64 bit visual studio solutions in a single solution? Cmake doesn't do that for me.
since Cmake generates 2 solutions in two different diectories, is there a way I can combine these two solutions by say editing .vcxproj files or something?

Comment: Is there any way to edit .vcxproj files and add some lines for x64 ?

Comment: CMake does not support that at all. Although you can do as your above comment mentions get CMake to edit the .vcxproj files. However remember that linking to other projects will not work automatically since it will pick the wrong libraries to link (32bit ones in x64 projects and visversa).

Comment: Any pointers for editing .vcxproj files for this purpose? How to do this?